# Django: Referencing a manytomany field that has been defined in another model

Tags: python, django, models

I'm trying to work out how to calculate the number of books written by an author. The book model sets up the manytomany field with the author model. I have no idea how even google something like this which I thought would be very simple to do but I don't even know how to start.

Here's the stripped down code:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    def books(self):
        """Return a list of comma separated list of books by the author"""
        pass

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

Maybe I could do a filter query to get books by a particular author but it doesn't seem like the django way to do it? I'm also not sure how to pass the filter function a python object rather than text.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you define a foreignkey or manytomany field, django sets up a reverse relation for you, which in your case is `book_set`. so something like:

```
def books(self):
    books = self.book_set.all()
    return ', '.join([book.title for book in books])
```

see [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) in the docs

Comment: Ahh, I knew django would have some shortcut to it, I just couldn't find it in the docs but there it is! Thanks a lot!